# Parser for the multipart format

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x

org.apache.http can work with multipart?

I send http request with header `Range : bytes=0-500,9000-9999`

I get file format:

```
--00000000000000001873
Content-Type: audio/mpeg
Content-Range: bytes 0-8999/4593415

ID3....bytes....
...bytes®
--00000000000000001873
Content-Type: audio/mpeg
Content-Range: bytes 9000-9999/4593415

ф....bytes...
...bytes
--00000000000000001873--
```

How to take only the bytes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Apache Mime4j` is your friend.

http://james.apache.org/mime4j/index.html

Answer (score 0):

you need to know the boundary (should be defined in the main response header)

when you see the boundary you can parse the subheader to find out what follows (in this case the content type and -range

note: the boundary is defined to be only found in the headers to delimit them